# How to find the interval of a constant moviment in a bezier path

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, bezier

I get the bezier value from a **path** like this (**note:** If there is another/better way to do that let me know, please):

```
public static Vector3 PathCubic (float t, Vector3[] path)
{
    if (t >= 1f)
        return path[path.Length - 1];

    // projects t in the path
    var projT = path.Length / 3 * t;

    // what interval t is (between P1 and P2 or between P2 and P3, etc)
    var range = (int)projT;

    // get the interval index
    var i = range * 3;
    var p0 = path[i + 0]; // first point
    var c0 = path[i + 1]; // control 1
    var c1 = path[i + 2]; // control 2
    var p1 = path[i + 3]; // second point

    // calculate bezier in the current interval
    return Cubic(projT - range, p0, c0, c1, p1);
}
```

So, supposing points `P1, P2, P3, P4`, `t = 0.0` is the first point `P1` and `t = 1.0` is the last point `P4`.

But, that doesn't give me a constant moviment over the bezier. Image bellow depicts what I mean. A `t = 0.5` give me different positions depending on points location.

[image]

I found I have to calculate the length of the path in order to achieve that. And here comes the problem. Once calculated this length, how can I calculate the **interval index**, as I did before? Or I will need to walk through each interval (`for` instruction) in order to find that?

```
// get the ***interval index***
var i = range * 3;
var p0 = path[i + 0]; // first point
var c0 = path[i + 1]; // control 1
var c1 = path[i + 2]; // control 2
var p1 = path[i + 3]; // second point
```

Comment: It is no clear what you want. Are you paths always straight segments? If not, do you need to find a point (coordinates) at `t*PathLength` distance along curve?

Comment: @MBo not straight.. that is just to illustrate.. its a bezier cubic path.

Comment: I don't understand - why do you need interval index? What does it mean for curved path (where control points don't lie on curve)?

Comment: I need to find what interval in the path (P1 to P2, or, P2 to P3, etc) it is, so i can calculate bezier on it. Maybe i'm doing some mistake thinking this way. idk.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MovingAlongCurveSpecifiedSpeed.pdf) of value.  You're on the right track. As you've noted the first step is to reparameterize your curve based on distance traveled (arc lengths).  It's a little more involved than I can fit in a comment but that paper hopefully gives you Google-able terms.

Comment: There are some related answers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-b%C3%A9zier-curves and http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/ is good. It has an example of drawing a dashed line which might help.

Comment: https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing

Answer (score 1):

There is no true solution but here is a usefull approximation:

First get the length of each segment. Let's say it's:

```
// |a b| is the operator of length between two points a and b
A=|P1 P2|=3.0
B=|P2 P3|=1.2
C=|P3 P4|=0.8
L=A+B+C=5.0 // length of the whole spline
```

Your `t=0.5` and is between points `P1` and `P2` - we know that because `t*L = 2.5` and length `A=3` (and `A` is first, so the immaginary length before was `0`).

We also know that the value of `t` that we want should be on `2.5/3.0 =~ 0.833` of the length between points `P1` and `P2`.

Note that `P1`was calculated with `t = 0` and `P2` with `t =~ 0.333`.

We can now find the fixed value of `t`: `Tfix=Mathf.Lerp(0, 0.333, 0.833) =~ 0.277`, where:
`0` - `t` of point `P1`
`0.333` - `t` of point `P2`
`0.833` - the approximated position of searched `t` relative to closest approximation points.

Finally to find the point you were searching for substitute `Tfix` for `t`: `PathCubic(Tfix)`

Also, think about using more approximation points. For more demanding uses I needed dividing the segment in 16 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical answer: in general you can't. There is no symbolic way to determine the length of your cubic curve (it'd require solving a 6th order polynomial, which cannot be with regular formula manipulations), so there's no way to straight-up compute which `t` value you need for distance `d` along your curve.

The fastest solution is typically to index your curve: at fixed t intervals, build a lookup table with the length of the curve up to that point. Then use that LUT to do estimation. If your curve is length 42, and your LUT is `distance = [0,5,12,25,37,42]` for corresponding `t = [0,1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,1]` then now you can use that data at moment to quickly estimate which `t` values you need to highlight which fixed distances, using simple linear interpolation.